# How can I make this "class-based view" work?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have been learning Django and now working on the class based view. I typed exactly as both official documentation and the book for beginner mentioned, but the code didn't work as they explained. Please teach me why this doesn't work.

The command prompt says  "File "C:\Users\yuto1\Desktop\book_study\Tabelog\urls.py", line 9, in 
path("list/", ReviewList.as_view(), name="ReviewList"),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'"

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from Tabelog import views
from Tabelog.views import ReviewList

app_name = "Tabelog"

urlpatterns = [
    path("lp/", views.lp,name="lp"),
    path("list/", ReviewList.as_view(), name="ReviewList"),
    path("detail/<str:store_name>",views.detail,name="detail"),
    path("form/",views.form,name="form"),
    path("form/fix/<str:pk>",views.form_fix,name="form_fix")
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from Tabelog.models import Tabelog
from Tabelog.forms import CreateTabelogForm
from django.views.generic import ListView

# Create your views here.
def lp(request):
    return render(request,"Tabelog/lp.html")

def ReviewList(ListView):
    model = Tabelog

def detail(request,store_name):
    detail = Tabelog.objects.get(store_name = store_name)
    context = {
        "detail":detail,
    }
    return render(request,"Tabelog/detail.html",context)

def form(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = CreateTabelogForm()
        context = {
            "form":form
        }
        return render(request,"Tabelog/form.html",context)

    else:
        form = CreateTabelogForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
            form = CreateTabelogForm(request.POST)
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect("Tabelog:list")

        else:
            form = CreateTabelogForm()
            context = {
                "form":form
            }
            return render(request,"Tabelog/form.html",context)

def form_fix(request,pk):
    review = get_object_or_404(Tabelog,pk=pk)
    print("success one")
    form = CreateTabelogForm(request.POST or None,instance=review)
    print("success two")

    if request.method == "GET":
        form = CreateTabelogForm(instance=review)
        context = {
            "form":form
        }
        return render(request,"Tabelog/form_fix.html",context)

    else:
        if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("Tabelog:list")

        else:
            form = CreateTabelogForm(instance=review)
            context = {
                "form":form
            }
            return render(request,"Tabelog/form_fix.html",context)
```

reviewlist_list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'diary/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for contents in object_list%}
<article class="store">
  <h1> <a href="{% url 'Tabelog:detail' contents.store_name %}">{{contents.store_name}}</a></h1>
  <h2>{{contents.get_stars_display}}</h2>
  <span>{{contents.outline}}</span>
</article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on class based view you need to specify the class name by keyword class not by def (it is for function based view), make changes in your code as shown below.

```
class ReviewList(ListView):
    model = Tabelog
```